# How to use import without causing compilation

Tags: typescript

In a project I am working on, I want to import some other files *in situ* and I don't want them to be compiled as they are already compiled using different settings. However, specifying rootdir has no effect, other than this error:

```
error TS6059: File 'G:/connector/api.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'G:/controller/api/controllers-src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

The files still get compiled and overall folder structure appears in my outDir.

```
import { getCustomers } from '../../../connector/api';
```